# AMPScript for product grid created from RSS feed

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We would like to populate a product grid pulled from an product category RSS feed. Below is code pulled from the [help doc](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/how_to_include_an_rss_feed_in_an_email_message_using_ampscript/) for using RSS feed in email.

Within the grid we need to include *product's* (title, image & link) for product positions 1-9 from the RSS feed (see link inside AMPScript).

From the "help" code, we've also added image + inserted a dynamic date statement `%%=Format(Now(),"MM-dd-yyyy")=%%` to update tracking parameters.

**Content Area**

```
%%before; httpget; 1 "http://www.nastygal.com/feed/clothes"%%
```

**AMPScript**

```
%%[

Var @xml, @titles, @title, @descs, @desc, @links, @link, @cnt

/* This line specifies the content area from which the RSS content will be pulled for the email message. */
Set @xml = ContentAreaByName("my contents\newarrivals_clothes_9") 

Set @titles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/title",1)
Set @links = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/link",1)
Set @images = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/img",1)

If RowCount(@titles) > 9 THEN
     SET @rows = 9
ELSE
    SET @rows = RowCount(@titles)
ENDIF

IF @rows >= 1 THEN

    for @cnt = 1 to @rows do

        Set @title = Field(Row(@titles,@cnt),"Value")
        Set @desc = Field(Row(@descs,@cnt), "Value")
        Set @link = Field(Row(@links,@cnt), "Value")
        Set @image = Field(Row(@images,@cnt), "Value") 

        ]%%

        <div style="border: 1px solid #444; background-color: #F7F7F7; margin: 0.76em 0; padding: 0.76em;">
            <h1 style="font: bold normal 1.0em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%" alias="%%=v(@title)="%%" title="%%=v(@title)=%% style="color: #000;">%%=v(@title)=%%</a>
            </h1>
            <span style="font: normal normal 0.76em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #444;">
                %%=v(@desc)=%%
            </span>
        </div>

    %%[ NEXT @cnt ]%%

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

**QUESTION**

Based on what we have, will the AMPScript understand appropriate values to pull in from RSS?

Did we insert @image correctly?

Answer (score 0):

No.  The XPath values in your `BuildRowSetFromXML()` functions don't match your RSS feed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
   <author>
      <name>Nasty Gal</name>
   </author>
   <id>Nasty Gal: clothes</id>
   <title>clothes</title>
   <updated>2015-08-05T02:33:12+00:00</updated>
   <entry>
      <id>$158.00</id>
      <link href="http://www.nastygal.com/clothes/nasty-gal-hear-me-rawr-moto-jacket" />
      <summary>http://i.ngimg.com/resources/nastygal/images/products/processed/56657.0.browse-l.jpg</summary>
      <title>Nasty Gal Hear Me Rawr Moto Jacket</title>
      <updated>2015-08-05T02:33:12+00:00</updated>
      <dc:date>2015-08-05T02:33:12+00:00</dc:date>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <id>$200.00</id>
      <link href="http://www.nastygal.com/clothes/nasty-gal-easy-rider-leather-skirt" />
      <summary>http://i.ngimg.com/resources/nastygal/images/products/processed/54770.0.browse-l.jpg</summary>
      <title>Nasty Gal Easy Rider Leather Skirt</title>
      <updated>2015-08-05T02:33:12+00:00</updated>
      <dc:date>2015-08-05T02:33:12+00:00</dc:date>
   </entry>
</feed>
```

If you want the links, titles and images, you'll need to reference them via XPATH with `//entry/title`, `//entry/link` and `//entry/summary`:

```
%%[

/* other AMPScript */

Set @titles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//entry/title",1)
Set @links = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//entry/link",1)
Set @images = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//entry/summary",1)

/* other AMPScript*/
]%%
```

You'll probably want to output the image in your `for` loop, also:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #444; background-color: #F7F7F7; margin: 0.76em 0; padding: 0.76em;">

    <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%" alias="%%=v(@title)="%%" title="%%=v(@title)=%%>
        <img style="display:block;" src="%%=v(@image)=%%"/>
    </a>

    <h1 style="font: bold normal 1.0em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%" alias="%%=v(@title)="%%" title="%%=v(@title)=%% style="color: #000;">%%=v(@title)=%%</a>
    </h1>

    <span style="font: normal normal 0.76em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #444;">
        %%=v(@desc)=%%
    </span>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.

Still unsure for what is supposed to be stored in the email message template vs. in the content area referenced in amp?

Comment: right now we have all the ampscript (listed above) inside the content area. In the email template it references the content area's name only (<custom type="content" name="newarrivals_clothes_9">). It throws an error for all the amp fields when we try to test send.

Comment: That's how I'd configure the template and email.  But I'd recommend not using a content area for the RSS feed -- just use the `set @xml = httpget("http://www.nastygal.com/feed/clothes")`